# Nodejs doesn't detect changes / automatically recompile on windows

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm running nodejs [6.10.2] on windows 10 (fully updated).  For some reason, after a while of working perfectly (30 minutes or so) the system stops triggering automatic recompiles when files change.  If I make a dozen or so changes it will eventually trigger the recompile.  The way I have been dealing with this is restarting npm but that is really annoying.

The 'old version' continues to run perfectly during this whole process.  Does anyone have any ideas on what might be going on?

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by node automatically recompiling files when changed? Or restarting npm? A normal node process doesn't hot-load new files if you change them on disk, though you can use something like nodemon to automatically restart your process when you change something. npm is a cli tool that will start up, do something, and shut down. If you have an npm script that stays keeps the process going, then the issue is likely with that instead. I'm not entirely sure you're naming the techs that you're having issue with correctly. Or I'm just very confused.

Comment: There is no such node.js version as 3.10.10.

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies.  To start, obviously I'm new to node.  Version of node is 6.10.2, I did npm --version prior.  So my default installation of node on windows will automatically detect a change to files (after I run npm start) and then recompile + reload localhost:3000.  This happens for the first 30 minutes of coding and then seems to stop.  I'm not sure if it is using something behind the scenes but I am not running anything special.  Any ideas? I'm confused too.

Comment: @hendr1x You need to share you build code. Probably you are using a tool that watches over your files and recompiles and that's not working. Likely a gulp or grunt file.

Comment: There's not enough information for us to answer. If you install nodejs you get two CLI tools: `node` and `npm`. Neither one does what you're saying, and a default project that you get from doing `npm init` won't have a start tag, and the default of `npm start` is just to do `node server.js`. When running `node script.js` it runs it, completes, and stops. If the script does something like listen on a port, it'll stay open but not reload files. You need something like nodemon to do that. I think you're using a project template from someone and without info about that we can't help.

Comment: Ah, that must be it.  I did start with facebook's 'Create React App'.  The project is public @ https://github.com/QuestionDevelopment/react-login